# Error in JavaScript OR jQuery select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

jQuery:

```
$("#div td").live("click", function(){

alert("Hellow");

});
```

JavaScript:

```
function alertH(){

alert("Hellow");

}
```

HTML jQuery:

```
<div>

<td>

<a>X</a>

<span> HI! </span>

</td>

</div>
```

Click on td and runs the jQuery function, but only if you click on td and not other tags inside, as in jQuery?

HTML JavaScript:

```
<div>

<td onClick="alertH()">

<span> Hummm </span>

<a> Delete </a>

</td>
</div>
```

How do in JavaScript, and it only runs if you click directly on td and not in other html tags inside

Performs this function only if you click the div function and not in other tags inside the div. How do the two methods above?

Comment: were is your table and tr(s) ??

Comment: I know it is just to demonstrate what I want to do there. You click the right element, the father. And not the elements within the parent element.

Comment: This question will be stored in Stackoverflow for others to learn from it, please don't post wrong code with excuse to make it simple.

Comment: I don't know what you observed, but even with jQuery the handler will be executed if you click on an element inside the `td` element. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/m4vw8/. Evem thought it is possible to achieve what you want, the question is whether it makes sense. The elements inside a cell will usually nearly completely fill the cell, so there is no space of the cell itself that could be clicked on.

Comment: Have you tried inside the function to check the "event.target" to see if you are clicking in the TD or one of his child?

Comment: Second example to my previous comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8dBu9/. You see how little spaces the cell consumes (red background)? Clicking on it is not *that* easy. So what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Another way is to add to the tags you dont want to execute is to add onClick="event.cancelBubble = true;"

Comment: Will someone stop talking so much and observes the code?...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear from the code what you are trying to do. Maybe "someone" is only trying to help you to explain your problem better so that you get proper help.

Comment: Here friends, you may entendão: http://jsfiddle.net/guin90/mb5BJ/

Comment: Even with the jsFiddle demo, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the alert only to be shown when the user clicks on the div with ID `show_modal`? If yes, just bind the event handler directly to that element.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by adding the code on each element you dont want to call a function

```
onClick="event.cancelBubble = true;"
```

Another way is to check in the callback called to see the Target there.

```
<div onClick="test()" id="run">
Click Works<br>
<label>Not Work</label>
</div>

function test(){
    if (event.target.id !== "run") return false;
    alert(event.target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just a moment, I'll try! But in Jquery, I type the function of td that clicking generates the alert (), but within the td has another function to click and open a window, then I click on the div function of the window from inside the td it also performs the function of alert. So wanted a code that forced the issue even if clicked on and not in another td element within it!

Comment: onClick="event.cancelBubble = true;"? cancelBubble? How is the code I use jquery?

Comment: Here friends, you may entendão: http://jsfiddle.net/guin90/mb5BJ/

Comment: We may be getting your question wrong. Is this what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/NtEFa/](http://jsfiddle.net/NtEFa/) Here I used the second option I specified.